# What connotation does "just so you know" have?

Tags: grammar

I came across the phrase 'just so you know' in the drama and it was used like "All right okay, just so you know, I'm not gonna make a turkey this year" I looked it over in a dictionary and I understood its meaning.  Does it always have a feeling that you're angry because someone's statement upset you?  Or is it used just to add some comment as the one you're talking with hasn't noticed it yet?

Comment: Where do you get the idea that it might "have a feeling that you're angry"? Please cite your dictionary reference and explain why it is unclear.

Comment: I just wrote it as I thought it makes sense.  It means 'angry feeling'.

Comment: It doesn’t imply that you’re angry by itself. It can be used perfectly neutrally. It’s not uncommon for it to be used in a very assertive, possibly aggressive, manner, but you’ll know not because it’s this phrase, but because of context, tone, and body language.

Comment: It means pretty much what it says -- "I'm just telling you this in case it's useful to you."  Like any such statement, it can be used in situations where someone is angry/irritated/offended:  "You just bad-mouthed Catholics, and, just so you know, I'm a Catholic."

Comment: That's interesting.  I've never heard 'Just so you know' before and the only phrase I knew was 'let me tell you one thing', which is probably the same meaning as 'just so you know'.

Comment: check out https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5808/what-does-just-so-you-know-mean

Comment: I think 'Let me tell you one thing…' is always either a slightly sarcastic shorthand for '… which you need to know, but apparently don't' or an attempt to get in the last word abut something disputed.

'Just so you know' as the others said, could certainly be neutral and it could also be very positive, as in 'I won't say more but if you're looking for someone to have fun with, Boy/Girlname is single again; just so you know…'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Just so you know' is a saying. It doesn't necessarily mean angry to me. It is more of a saying added onto words to emphasize the information, so that people will react to the information. It is often giving information that will affect the receiver somehow. It can be used sarcastically or with emotion, to point out something that the speaker feels the listener should already know about and indirectly demand that they stop doing it. ex. Just so you know, you shouldn't leave a dirty knife lying on the counter like that. But, it can also be used neutrally to emphasize information. This is just my feeling about the saying.